# Static Variable in VBScript

Tags: variables, vbscript, static

How to define static variable in VBScript. I'm trying to iterate through folders for which i need a static variable. In vba its simple

```
Static val As Integer
val = 1
```

How to achieve this in vbscript. If we cant define them, then how to achieve the functionality of static variable in VBScript.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript doesn't have a `Static` classifier. Global variables are probably the closest you get.

Answer (score -4):

What you want is a Constant.
Just put Const in front of your variable name and your variable is now a constant.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/16twy8ed%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: [Static variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) are not constants.